# How to pass values from parent job to child job in talend

Tags: talend, rest-client

I'm using talend big data & created the two jobs(parent & child).Both the jobs using tRESTClient with different URLs. In parent Job, getting some values and trying to pass the values to child job.Then I want to store those values(parent & child values ) into mongoDB.
Parent URL & Job:
 `https://api.github.com/users/sample/repos` &  `tRESTClient --> tXMLMap --> tBufferOutput --> tRunJob`

Parent Values: `stargazers_count` & `watchers_count`

Child URL & Job: 
`https://api.github.com/repos/sample/awesome-ciandcd/commits` & `tRESTClient --> tXMLMap --> tMongoDBOutput`

Child Job tXMLMap:[image]

Child Values: `date` & `message`

Child Values are directly getting from URL & parent values get through the context variable.But my job stored the parent values as NULL.

Parent tRunJob Configuration:[image]

How to store the parent values into mongoDB?

Comment: can you please show me the tRunJob configuration of parent job?

Comment: tRunJob Configuration screenshot added in the above post.

Answer (score 0):

pass your context from parent to child by explicitly define in tRunJob component.

i suppose you are using tBuffereOutput for storing those values which you want to pass to child job, but u dont need it.
directly connect your tXMLMap to tRunJob with main flow and sync your schema in tRunJob.

create all the context variable in child job which you want to pass from parent job.

then in tRunJob, in Context Param all your schema field will reflect under parameter field.
place your context variable name against them. this will solve your doubt.

Hope this help :)

Comment: I have modified job & added the params in tRunJob. But still i'm getting NULL values to the parent columns.

Comment: could you please show me the change you made in job (parent and child)

Comment: Is this really working? Passing rows from a parent to a child job? I have tried that but it didn‘t work.